# Why do I get a different number of hits in a MySQL query if I use an index or not

Tags: mysql, database-indexes

I am new in MySQL and I do not understand, why if I use index on JSON column, result set is different as without index.

I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE jsontest (
jsondata JSON
);
```

Table is filled up with 50000 JSONs and one filed in json is also:

```
 "allowedNfTypes": ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]}
```

This field in some cases have 1 or 2 or 3 values in array (but there are about 10 string options - let's say from "aaa" to "iii").
In some cases this filed does not exist  at all.

Then if I execute:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM jsontest WHERE "AMF" MEMBER OF(jsondata->'$.allowedNfTypes')
```

I get:

```
10045 rows in set (0.21 sec)
```

Then I created an index:

```
CREATE INDEX allowedNfTypes_index ON jsontest((CAST(jsondata->'$.allowedNfTypes' AS CHAR(128) ARRAY)))
```

And the same query

```
SELECT * FROM jsontest WHERE "AMF" MEMBER OF(jsondata->'$.allowedNfTypes');
```

return much less hits:

```
1402 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Any idea why?

Comment: It is very strange. The index creation shouldn't effect the output - this contradicts with SQL principles. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f1d1f17e5a009f1a0eaf66a92c7c861), try to edit it, add your data and reproduce the issue. Also try SELECT INTO OUTFILE and compare the outputs - maybe you'll find what causes the issue...

Comment: Yes I try also comparing the output data, but... @Akina maybe you can help me with my original generated json file: [link]: (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12ozf_1BJt-zSaRUCJlachjjyXBUc4neJ?usp=sharing). As you can see, I am searching: WHERE "AMF" MEMBER OF ...

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded your data file.

CLI output copy:

```sql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 16
Server version: 8.0.23 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> CREATE TABLE jsontest (
    -> jsondata JSON
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\test_data.json' INTO TABLE jsontest;
Query OK, 50000 rows affected (15.50 sec)
Records: 50000  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jsontest WHERE "AMF" MEMBER OF(jsondata->'$.allowedNfTypes');
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|    10045 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.32 sec)

mysql> CREATE INDEX allowedNfTypes_index ON jsontest((CAST(jsondata->'$.allowedNfTypes' AS CHAR(128) ARRAY)));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.88 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jsontest WHERE "AMF" MEMBER OF(jsondata->'$.allowedNfTypes');
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|    10045 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.28 sec)
```

Also original query (not `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ..` but `SELECT * FROM ..`) was tested - the result is the same.

The issue was not reproduced.

---

After version updating till actual 8.0.28 the issue is reproduced. The amount of rows selected with the index is the same - 1402.

After adding autoincremented primary key `ALTER TABLE jsontest ADD COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;` the amount of rows selected with index alters to 1448.

Comparing the rows selected with and without index I have found that:

1. There is a lot of duplicates in `jsondata->'$.allowedNfTypes'`.
2. For each unique `jsondata->'$.allowedNfTypes'` value only the rows which have created unique `id` less than approximately 6800 are selected with the index by `jsondata->'$.allowedNfTypes'`, all another rows with duplicated value are not selected.
3. Deleting the rows which have `id` value above some N  decreases the amount of rows returned by the query without the index and does not alter the amount of rows returned by the query with index (tested N = 40000, 25000, 10000, 7500, 7000, 6800). When N is 6797 or less the amount of rows selected become equal.
4. I have tried to add generated column which extracts this property as JSON array with `aLTER TABLE jsontest ADD COLUMN allowedNfTypes JSON AS (CAST(jsondata->'$.allowedNfTypes' AS JSON));`, create multivalued index by this column and use this column insrtead of the whole JSON. The amount of rows selected with index increases till 1498. The value of N is 5097.
5. Then I add the index described by OP (the table contains 2 indices - by original column and by generated one) - and the query returns 10045! I drops the generated column and the index by it - 10045. I drop the index by original column and re-create it - again 1498.

There was a lot of additional experiments, but their results are less interesting.

Looks like a bug. Reproduceable bug. I think that you may repeat my expriment (and/or perform your own) and report this to MySQL bugtrack.

Comment: This is strange. I re-created the database and the result is the same, only 1402 hits with the index. The only difference that I see is that I use: Server version: 8.0.28 MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Comment: I have reproduced the issue after upgrading from 8.0.23 to 8.0.28. Will investigate.

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=106621 "Fixed in 8.0.30"